# R Correlation matrix is too slow - Running out of CPU

Tags: r, memory, parallel-processing, cpu, cpu-usage

My goal is to generate a correlation matrix of 5 samples. I have >100 genes and and >5000 lncs that i would like to correlate each gene to each lncs.

These are excerpts of my 2 input files:
sigPCGDNp63KC.1.5f.p0.05.nofdr.v1.txt

```
GeneName    DNp63KC-1   DNp63KC-2   WTKC-1  WTKC-2  WTKC-3
Lphn2   15.5398625  14.6537125  24.7852 23.5052 31.387625
Ctbs    4.36166625  4.45151125  2.4854475   2.16731125  2.34724
Itgb4   0.262007875 0.203484625 114.0795    143.964875  128.9605
Tgs1    7.635635    7.68811875  4.86758 5.32287375  4.45235375
Sdr16c5 0   0   3.2194225   1.7414225   3.47433375
Cast    78.8140125  78.91005    150.98875   122.6945    136.10925
Rhobtb3 13.0326125  10.931615   5.2524  5.09462 5.72327625
Hyal1   2.70114125  3.75574625  23.3396625  16.00245    30.6743
Hpgds   0.030215425 0.03004895  6.80123625  5.15387875  5.54338
```

siglncDNp63KC.1.5f.p0.05.nofdr.vYan.txt:

```
GeneName    DNp63KC-1   DNp63KC-2   WTKC-1  WTKC-2  WTKC-3
Gm17597 0.166118375 0.225398    0.038626725 0.024296575 0.041762288
A930012L18Rik   0.328463    0.23827525  0.0811242   0.10030255  0.085353788
Gm3764  2.1724375   1.53431125  0   0   0
Mir143hg    1.5451225   1.67842125  0.02413365  0.119622663 0.069306413
1700028E10Rik   0   0   0.047058525 0.030703513 0.0229409
Gm26523 0.171209    0.16649225  0   0.013628296 0
Gm26527 14.1213375  14.28183125 0.744736875 6.869945    1.201424375
A530013C23Rik   0.292076125 0.361674375 0.1364565   0.092379575 0.0746007
```

To that, I wrote the following R script that works without errors on small samples:

```
experiment_name <- 'KC-lnc.vs.PCG'
genes <- read.delim(file="sigPCGDNp63KC.1.5f.p0.05.nofdr.v1.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
lnc <- read.delim(file="siglncDNp63KC.1.5f.p0.05.nofdr.vYan.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1) 

x <- rownames(genes[1:nrow(genes),])
y <- rownames(lnc[1:nrow(lnc),])

d_p<-NULL #dataframe for pearson output

mat_sig_p<-matrix(0,nrow(genes),nrow(lnc)) #matrix for significnat pearson
rownames(mat_sig_p) <- rownames(genes)
colnames(mat_sig_p) <- rownames(lnc)

mat_all_p<-matrix(0,nrow(genes),nrow(lnc)) #matrix for all pearson
rownames(mat_all_p) <- rownames(genes)
colnames(mat_all_p) <- rownames(lnc)


d_s<-NULL #dataframe for spearman output

mat_sig_s<-matrix(0,nrow(genes),nrow(lnc)) #matrix for significnat spearman
rownames(mat_sig_s) <- rownames(genes)
colnames(mat_sig_s) <- rownames(lnc)

mat_all_s<-matrix(0,nrow(genes),nrow(lnc)) #matrix for all spearman
rownames(mat_all_s) <- rownames(genes)
colnames(mat_all_s) <- rownames(lnc)

#result=cor.test(as.numeric(genes[4,]), as.numeric(lnc[2,]), method='pearson')
#abs(result[["estimate"]])

for (i in x){
  for (j in y) {
    result_p<-cor.test(as.numeric(genes[i,]), as.numeric(lnc[j,]), method='pearson')
    result_s<-cor.test(as.numeric(genes[i,]), as.numeric(lnc[j,]), method='spearman')
    d_p<-rbind(d_p, data.frame(i, j, result_p[c("estimate","p.value","statistic","method")], abs(result_p[["estimate"]]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) #to write output of loop to an empty dataframe
    d_s<-rbind(d_s, data.frame(i, j, result_s[c("estimate","p.value","statistic","method")], abs(result_s[["estimate"]]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) #to write output of loop to an empty dataframe
    mat_all_p[i,j] <- result_p[["estimate"]] #double brackets to make it numerical
    mat_all_s[i,j] <- result_s[["estimate"]] #double brackets to make it numerical
    if (result_p["p.value"]<0.05){
    mat_sig_p[i,j] <- result_p[["estimate"]]
    }
    if (result_s["p.value"]<0.05){
      mat_sig_s[i,j] <- result_s[["estimate"]]
    }
  }
}
```

I then output each of the matrices to a tab delimited file.

While the above runs for combination of 20 genes and 20 lncs. Any big number of each takes >12 hours and it is still not done. I am running it on a Cluster and on local computer and it is still not done. When I am looking at the memory being used while the process is being run, i see that not al my memory is consumed.. barely 400 mb being used by R, whereas 100% of my CPU power is taken by R.

How can I divide CPU usage to allow the above process to run successfully without having to wait this long? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Please note that i have basic understanding of the memory and CPU usage.

Comment: Your code is really inefficient for a number of reasons. The most obvious is that cor(x,y) = cor(y,x)... so you don't need to calculate half the correlations that you're currently calculating.

Comment: Yes, you could parallelize this. But I don't see the point in it until you get rid of the current inefficiencies.

Comment: @Alex: Can you please point me to where cor(x,y) is being calculated as cor(y,x). In fact, I wrote the script in a way to avoid this which is why I have 2 input files, and each file has its own list of DIFFERENT genes/lncs to avoid calculate the same correlation.

Comment: I may be overlooking something, so I'd appreciate if you can point it out. thanks0

Comment: In your example, `result_p` and `result_s` are the same operation. Furthermore, growing objects in loops is notoriously slow in R. Anything else is hard to say, as your example is not reproducible. But I agree with @Alex that optimizing your current code can win you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks @Heroka. The methods are different in result_p and result_s. One is spearman, while the other is pearson correlation. Do you mean to split each into a separate code as a start?

Comment: @BioProgram your loops have `i= 1,..., n; j= 1,..., m` therefore you calculate every element in the matrix. You should loop such that you only calc the upper or lower triangular matrix.